# SQL [Hard query - to make or to avoid]

Tags: sql

```
SELECT Name, 
       ( NOT (ID_ListGroupParIzm 
              IN (SELECT ID_Param 
                    FROM TbUserParam
                   WHERE ID_User=:ID_User
                 )
              )  
       ) Visi 
  FROM CfgListParIzm 
 WHERE ID_ListGroupParIzm=:ID_ListGroupParIzm
```

Errors :

```
Message 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
Incorrect syntax near the keyword "NOT".
Message 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 2
Incorrect syntax near the construction ":".
```

added : 
I'll try to explain what I want with it.

I need a name from one table and a BOOL value for each Node wich will be false if ID_ListGroupParIzm IN (SELECT ID_Param FROM TbUserParam
WHERE ID_User=:ID_User

And ID_ListGroupParIzm (from CfgListParIzm ) = ID_Param (from TbUserParam)
forget to say :(

btw : looking like select can't return logics value . . . 
How to get my purpose then :(

added a try :

```
SELECT  Name,
        COALESCE(
        (
        SELECT  TOP 1 0
        FROM    TbUserParam
        WHERE   TbUserParam.ID_User = :ID_User
                AND TbUserParam.ID_Param = CfgListParIzm.ID_ListParIzm
        ), 1) Visi
FROM    CfgListParIzm
WHERE   CfgListParIzm.ID_ListGroupParIzm = :ID_ListGroupParIzm
```

error :
    Message 102, Level 15, State 1, line 6
Incorrect syntax near the construction ":".

But ... sure >_< I need to remake it as a Procedure, Thank you.

Comment: Why do you have a NOT in your select clause?  What are you trying to do?

Comment: added to first question :) sorry for bit confusing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT  Name,
        COALESCE(
        (
        SELECT  TOP 1 0
        FROM    TbUserParam
        WHERE   ID_User = :ID_User
                AND ID_ListGroupParIzm = :ID_ListGroupParIzm
        ), 1) Visi
FROM    CfgListParIzm
WHERE   ID_ListGroupParIzm = :ID_ListGroupParIzm
```