# SQL [Conversion to bool]

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, casting

**C++Builder ADOQuery SQLServer**

I'm using a stored procedure with this select

```
SELECT  Name,
        COALESCE(
        (
        SELECT  TOP 1 0
        FROM    TbUserParam
        WHERE   TbUserParam.ID_User = @ID_User
                AND TbUserParam.ID_Param = CfgListParIzm.ID_ListParIzm
        ), 1) Visi
FROM    CfgListParIzm
WHERE   CfgListParIzm.ID_ListGroupParIzm = @ID_ListGroupParIzm
```

[Stuff about this query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2109489/sql-hard-query-to-make-or-to-avoid)

in my query with SQL string :

```
FlowClientHardQ  :ID_User, :ID_ListGroupParIzm
```

then DataSource and DBGrid with CheckBox fields. [Source](http://delphi.about.com/od/usedbvcl/l/aa082003a.htm)

So I need a bool (or bit) field there from my ADO Query.
How / Where can I convert it ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Cast to bit?

```
SELECT  Name,
        CAST(
        COALESCE(
        (
        SELECT  TOP 1 0
        FROM    TbUserParam
        WHERE   TbUserParam.ID_User = @ID_User
                AND TbUserParam.ID_Param = CfgListParIzm.ID_ListParIzm
        ), 1) as bit) Visi
FROM    CfgListParIzm
WHERE   CfgListParIzm.ID_ListGroupParIzm = @ID_ListGroupParIzm
```

But can you not rewrite the query thus to avoid the subquery:

```
SELECT
    C.Name,
    CAST(CASE WHEN T2.ID_Param IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END as bit) AS Visi
FROM
    CfgListParIzm C
    LEFT JOIN
    (
    SELECT
        T.ID_Param
    FROM
        TbUserParam T
    WHERE
        T.ID_User = @ID_User
    ) T2 On T2.ID_Param = C.ID_ListParIzm
WHERE
    C.ID_ListGroupParIzm = @ID_ListGroupParIzm
```

Comment: yes it works , thank you , but I still got some strange trouble somewhere "Cannot find the field Visi" (only on run program) ...
thank you also for avoid subquery !

Answer (score 6):

Maybe a CAST to BIT?

```
SELECT CAST(COALESCE(NULL,1) AS BIT)
```

**UPDATE**
 You could use is ISNULL() as well.
`SELECT CAST(ISNULL(NULL,1) AS BIT)`