# VCL SQL [Query parameters error]

Tags: sql, c++builder, vcl

**C++Builder ADOQuery SQLServer**

Continue of [This questions line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2115546/sql-convertation-to-bool)

using this select with procedure :

```
    SELECT
    C.Hint,
    CAST(CASE WHEN T2.ID_Param IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END as bit) AS Visi
FROM
    CfgListParIzm C
    LEFT JOIN
    (
    SELECT
        T.ID_Param
    FROM
        TbUserParam T
    WHERE
        T.ID_User = @ID_User
    ) T2 On T2.ID_Param = C.ID_ListParIzm
WHERE
    C.ID_ListGroupParIzm = @ID_ListGroupParIzm
```

---

Code :

```
AQ4->Close();
AQ4->Parameters->Items[1]->Value=(int)TS->Tabs->Objects[NewTab];
AQ4->Open();
```

Error :

```
List index of bounds (1)
```

But I can see this error only on run program.
Test query->grid activation works normal (with manually setup properties)

also if I do

```
            AQ4->Close();
//        AQ4->Parameters->Items[1]->Value=(int)TS->Tabs->Objects[NewTab];
          AQ4->Open();
```

error :

```
AQ4: Field 'Visi' not found
```

AQ4 SQL :

```
FlowClientHardQ  :ID_User, :ID_ListGroupParIzm
```

I also tough about DBGrid&Checkbox compability ([Source](http://delphi.about.com/od/usedbvcl/l/aa082003a.htm)) but as my field is normal bit I think that's not trouble, I made a mistake somewhere else...

Comment: I don't think you should "debug by question" !
Seems to me, you got an answer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2115546/sql-convertation-to-bool and now you've got another problem; and next will be F10 for the next line to debug :)

Comment: no please ... you wrong... I asked previews question because of same problem, I just tough convert to bool could helps me, but it doesn't. So now I show the main trouble. Just Can't understand why I've got 2 parameters and all works correct, but when start the program ShowMessage ( AQ4->Parameters->Count ); shows 1 ... also my debugger is broken by some 1337 components >___<

Comment: Try assigning the SQL query before the line `AQ4->Parameters->Items[1]->Value=(int)TS->Tabs->Objects[NewTab];`
(the query, once assigned, will be parsed), then try to assign the parameter values. Else, clear the parameters, and assign both, in order

Comment: If you can, I suggest you stop using C++ Builder. It is nothing but a pain - trust me, it SUCKS. Use Delphi instead, or switch to "standard" tools like Microsoft of Java - it will help you in the long run.

Comment: oh ... I know a lot of Holy war stuff, but I think C# is better. So I assigned it already. I can see both of parameters. But it they disappears on run, even disappears Visi output field. I really don't know why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure about C++ builder, but in Delphi VCL, input parameters shall be marked with : and not with @.

First, put the query at design time in a query component and inspect the parameters property.  If there's no parameters defined, try changing the @ for :

Now, you are making more than one question here... so, let's go step by step.

Comment: Sorry but that question was already solved. Thank you for interest. I just don't know how to mark it solved without answers